# Select product from the list

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have been working on this project for quite a while and still I am stuck on this code. Here's the page where I can show the product list:

```
@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die();
@mysql_select_db("product") or die();

$result=mysql_query("select * from product_list ORDER BY name ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  a href="show.php?code=$row['serial']|$row['name']
  $row['description']
```

show.php is:

```
//connect to server and select database; you may need it
@mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die();
@mysql_select_db("bibendum") or die();

$serial = intval($_GET['serial']);
$query = "SELECT serial, name, desription FROM product_list WHERE serial = {$serial}"; 

echo "{$row[name]}";
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: serial in show.php on line 7
>   Notice: Undefined index: serial in show.php on line 8
>   Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in show.php on line 10
>   Notice: Undefined variable: row in show.php on line 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this:

```
 $serial = intval($_GET['serial']);
$query = "SELECT serial, name, desription FROM product_list WHERE serial = {$serial}"; 

echo "{$row[name]}";
```

Should be this:

```
    $serial = intval($_GET['code']);
$query = "SELECT serial, name, desription FROM product_list WHERE serial = '".$serial."'"; 
echo $row['name'];
```

In the above you assign the query but you will still need to execute the query to get a result.

And this will not work to pass $_GET:

```
 a href="show.php?code=$row['serial']|$row['name']
$row['description']
```

If you are learning DO NOT start by using mysql..... Use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

I would also caution that you check $_GET['serial'] is valid and not for example 0.